# Changing Excel Vertical data to Horizontal [NOT TRANSPOSE]

Tags: excel

I am regularly coming across the need to take a list of items tied to an identifier (like an order number) and shift it to be one record.

i.e.

```
a   | b
101 | medium t-shirt
101 | medium socks
```

to

```
a   | b              | c
101 | medium t-shirt | medium socks
```

Any ideas on how to easily accomplish this?  Keeping in mind, I want to do this to a list 500 lines long.

Comment: Yes - you can use VBA for this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example provided something like this should work (I'm saying *should* because I don't have Excel at hand, so the code is untested):

```vb
Sub JoinByID()

    Dim dct As Dictionary
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim iIDCol As Integer
    Dim rFirst As Range
    Dim sID As String
    Dim col As Collection
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim vLoopIDs As Variant, vLoopVals As Variant

    Set rFirst = Sheets(1).Range("A1") 'change to where your data starts
    Set ws = rFirst.Parent
    iIDCol = rFirst.Column
    ' loop through data and collect based on ID
    For i = rFirst.Row + 1 To rFirst.End(xlDown).Row
        sID = ws.Cells(i, iIDCol).Value
        If dct.Exists(sID) Then
           dct(sID).Add ws.Cells(i, iIDCol + 1).Value
        Else
           Set col = New Collection
           col.Add ws.Cells(i, iIDCol + 1).Value
           dct.Add sID, col
        End If
    Next i

    ' drop the data in a new sheet
    Set wsNew = Worksheets.Add
    i = 0
    With wsNew
         For Each vLoopIDs In dct.Keys
             i = i + 1
             .Cells(i, 1) = vLoop
             j = 1
             For Each vLoopVals In dct(vLoop)
                 j = j + 1
                 .Cells(i, j) = vLoopVals
             Next vLoopVals
         Next vLoopIDs
    End With

End Sub
```

**Note**: you need to add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime to have `Dictionary` available.

Answer (score 0):

Enter in C2:

```
=IF(D2=FALSE,B3,B2)
```

in D2:

```
=ISODD(ROW())
```

and copy both down to suit.

Select all, Copy, Paste Special, Values over the top. Filter to select TRUE in ColumnD and delete all visible below header. Unfilter, remove filter and delete ColumnD.